# In Javascript, why am I able to print the value of a forEach but not return the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, undefined

```
const weatherCodes = {
    thunderstorm: range(200, 232),
    drizzle: range(300, 321),
    rain: range(500, 531),
    snow: range(600, 622),
    atmosphere: range(701, 781),
    clear: [800],
    cloudy: range(801, 804)
  };

  const getWeatherCode = () => {
    for (let key in weatherCodes) {
      let obj = weatherCodes[key];
      obj.forEach((element) => {
        if (element === weather.weatherID) {
          console.log(key);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  getWeatherCode(); // cloudy
```

I'm fetching the weatherID (804) from an API.

But if I change the "console.log(key)" to "return key" then I get undefined when I assign the function to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` has no return value. If you'd like to return a value, try using `map` instead.